# Boats and Streams in Maths

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**At his Usual Rowing Rate, Rahul can travel 12 miles downstream in a certain river in 6 hours lessthan it takes him to travel the  same distance upstream.But if he could double his usual rowing rate for his 24 Miles round trip, the Downstream  12 miles would then take only one hour lessthan the upstream 12 miles . what is the speed of the Current Miles in Hour**

My Logic:
Let the speed of the water be x and speed of the Man is y
If water and Rahul can travel in the same Direction then the Relative speed will be x-y after that how to solve this and how to approach this Question

Comment: @anyone is not anyone… and have you tried doing it yourself? The attempts can go below the question statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d=vt \implies t=\frac dv$

when he rows at speed $y$ his speed downstream is $y+x$ and his upstream speed is $ y-x$

when he rows at speed $2y$ his speed downstream is $2y+x$ and his upstream speed is $ 2y-x$

use this to set up equations for time differences.

e.g. the second equation would be ...

$$\frac{ 12}{2y-x} - \frac{ 12}{2y+x} = 1 $$

You will then have 2 equations to solve for 2 unknowns